Apparent bug in community leaderboards?
I was idly clicking around earlier and got to the community leaderboard. I saw a couple users I was familiar with and that was all well and good but then I noticed that at the top of the page, where I’m listed above the leaderboard, I see this-

-here, I am “not currently ranked” and have no measured rep change, while I am ranked on the leaderboard differently-

-there, I’m clearly ranked #16 and have a rep change of -1.
Is this a bug on the leaderboard or have I gravely misunderstood something? For clarity, this is the page that seems to be bugged.

In the table the first/top line always displays the user generating the page, i.e. you. The texts  “not currently ranked” and "rep needed" are indeed confusing.

I got that part - in fact I think it’s nice to see your own ranking right up top instead of having to scroll. Should the ranking and rep changes be displayed up there too, though, or is that by design?

Looks like the bug only occured when the URL is linked to a user. What do you see when there's no user ID on the URL?

@AndrewT. Bug is indeed gone when no user ID in the URL.
